# rearrange boxes when one is removed

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of divs that the user can create and which represent messaging boxes. When a user clicks on one of their friends' names a box is created. I have been able to make it so that when a new box is created it is positioned the right distance away, but I have not been able to figure out how to make it so that when a box is removed, the other boxes are moved over to fill the void and make space for new boxes. I know I need to use foreach but I do not know how to reference the boxes. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#chatbox{
    border:2px solid #0969A2;
    height:250px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#fff;
position:fixed;
z-index:11002;
padding:3px;
}

    $('#open-chat').live('click', function() {
    var user=$(this).attr('data-name');
    //check if bar exists
    if ($("#bar-icon[data-name="+user+"]").length == 0){
        $('.dockleft-block').append('<div id="bar-icon" data-name="'+user+'">'+user+'</div>');
        $('body').append('<div id="chatbox" data-name="'+user+'"></div>');

        //position new boxes           
        $("#chatbox[data-name="+user+"]").css('bottom', '37px');

        var chatBoxeslength = $("div[id=chatbox]").length-1;

        if (chatBoxeslength == 0) {
            $("#chatbox[data-name="+user+"]").css('left', '35px');
        } else {
            width = (chatBoxeslength)*(225+7)+20;
            $("#chatbox[data-name="+user+"]").css('left', width+'px');
            $("#bar-icon[data-name="+user+"]").css('left', width-35+'px');
        }

    }
    //end if length
    });                                       
    //end click function


    $('.closechatbox').live('click', function() {
    user=$(this).attr('data-name');     
    $("#chatbox[data-name="+user+"]").remove();
    $("#bar-icon[data-name="+user+"]").remove();
//need to rearrange other boxes
    });
```

**UPDATE**

this was the solution on another chat script but I do not understand it
anantgarg.com/chat/sampleb.php
how do they reference each box as #chatbox_"+chatboxtitle successfully?

```
function restructureChatBoxes() {
    align = 0;
    for (x in chatBoxes) {
        chatboxtitle = chatBoxes[x];

        if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display') != 'none') {
            if (align == 0) {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', '20px');
            } else {
                width = (align)*(225+7)+20;
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', width+'px');
            }
            align++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just have a reference to an array of the chat-window divs. Then as you add and remove them, adjust the array. After you adjust the array, you should just reposition everything in the array.

Something along these lines:

```
var chatWindows = [];
var windowWidth = 100;
var padding = 10;

function newChatWindow(divElement)
{
   chatWindows.push(divElement);
   reposition();
}

function reposition()
{
   var el = null;
   for (var i = 0; i < chatWindows.length; i++)
   {
      el = chatWindows[i];
      el.style.bottom = 10
      el.style.right = windowWidth * i + padding;
   }
}

function removeChatWindow(index)
{
   var el = chatWindows[index];
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
   var newArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < chatWindows.length - 1; i++)
   {
      if (i != index)
      {
          newArr.push(chatWindows[i]);
      }
   }
   chatWindows = newArr;
   reposition();
}
```

Comment: While your answer was not exactly what I needed, it was close and put me on track looking into arrays and such. Thanks bro, appreciate your time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I can get a solid mental picture of how the boxes are laid out when you render them, but you might not need to rearrange them all when you remove one.  For instance, if you float every new div left inside some container, when you remove one, all the rest will shift left and fill the void.  It's like a stack of books held in the pile by gravity.  Deftly pull one out, and the rest prompty settle into the space.

I understand that this may not quite fit the bill, but it's a lot simpler than programattically moving all the rest and filling the gap yourself.  You get the rearrangement for free.

Comment: I updated my code to show what the person who wrote that chat from the site did, but I can't understand what it means or how it works

Comment: also they are fixed position so they cannot float